# Java - static methods and static variable

Tags: java

I have a question that I can't answer

which one is **NOT** true!

1. satic methods can access to static variable and static methods
2. static methods can access to non-static variable and non-static methods
3. non-static methods can access to static variable
4. non-static methods can access to static methods

Comment: I bet you could maybe write a program and find out. :-) Unless you are having problems understanding any of the terminology?

Comment: Have you tried to check these statements?

Comment: They're all true.  See my comment under Abimaran's answer.

Comment: @David Wallace I don't thing they are all true. 2. is false I think

Comment: @Eypros in almost every Java program, a static method called `main` creates an object then calls a non-static method on that object.  That is, a static method accesses a non-static method.  If 2 were false, almost every Java program wouldn't run.

Comment: Well in order to be precise a static method cannot access a non-static method or instance variable **directly**. I am guessing this is all about. When a statement like the one in 2 is given it must be fulfilled in both parts and also it should be done in a direct manner. Indirect access is like saying a private instance member is accessible through setters and getters so it can be accessed. Anyway, I would argue that the answer of @Abimaran Kugathasan is more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

static methods can access to static variable and static methods :- **true**

**Reason** :-class level fields/methods can access the other class level fields/methods

static methods can access to non-static variable and non-static method :- **false**

**Reason** :-class level fields/methods can not access the object level fields/methods as there is a probability object has not been created yet

non-static methods can access to static variable :- **true**

**Reason** :-Object level fields/methods can access the class level fields/methods as  its logical

non-static methods can access to static methods :- **true**

**Reason** :-Object level fields/methods can access the class level fields/methods as  its logical

Answer (score 1):

2nd is partially wrong.

Static method can't directly access non static method. But, they can access non static methods on an object corresponding to the methods.

Comment: +1 for "partially".  Obviously, a static method can access a non-static method or variable if it has access to an instance of the class, or can create an instance of the class.  The people who set these terrible exam questions should be far more careful.

Answer (score 0):

2 is **FALSE** Because at the time you call a static method it is not guaranteed, that the instance (non-static) variables/functions exist.

Answer (score 0):

No 2 is not True.

Static methods can only access static members and variables.

Non-static methods can access both static and non-static members and variables.